# vueJs equivalent of jQuery slideDown/slideUp or slideToggle

Tags: vue.js

I'm experimenting with vue for the first time.

I've replaced a jquery show/hide that was using `.slideDown() / .slideUp()` with `v-show` - however I much prefer the animation of jQuery's slideup/down. Is there an easy way to do this with vue?

Simplified code here:

```
<nav class="bg-blue" role="navigation">
  <div class="container classes here">
    <div class="classes here">
      <h1 class="classes here"> 
        <a href="/" class="classes here">Site Name
        </a>
      </h1>

      <button class="classes here"  @click="isShowing ^= true">
        hamburger svg here
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="main-nav classes here" v-show="!isShowing">
      <div class="classes here">
        <!-- nav items here -->
      </div>
    </div>

  </div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Please advise.

Comment: With jQuery, these animations are JavaScript based. With Vue.js the idea is to start these animations conditionally with JavaScript but then use CSS animations for the actual animation. See here for more details: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html In your case, you could e.g. animate the CSS `min-height` property.

Answer (score 1):

You can install modules for this, or you can write a custom component. I suggest the second option.

```
<template>

    <div>

        <button @click="isShowing">
            hamburger svg here
        </button>

        <!-- animation of appearance/disappearance.
        More info: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html -->
        <!-- The attribute "name" is used to create custom classes
         that are applied during animation -->
        <transition name="main-nav"
                    @enter="transitionStep1"
                    @after-enter="transitionStep2"
                    @before-leave="transitionStep3"
                    @after-leave="transitionStep4">

            <div class="main-nav" v-show="!active">
                <div class="classes here">Some text</div>
            </div>

        </transition>

    </div>

</template>

<script>

    export default {
        name: "Accordion",
        data() {
            return {
                // set the variable that will hide/show the block
                active: false
            }
        },
        methods: {
            isShowing() {
                // change the value of the variable that will hide/show the block
                this.active = !this.active;
            },
            transitionStep1(el) {
                // set the block height at the moment of its appearance
                el.style.height = el.scrollHeight + 'px'
            },

            transitionStep2(el) {
                // remove inline styles from the block after animation of its appearance
                el.style.height = ''
            },

            transitionStep3(el) {
                // set the height of the block at the beginning of its disappearance animation
                el.style.height = el.scrollHeight + 'px'
            },

            transitionStep4(el) {
                // remove inline styles from the block after the animation of its disappearance
                el.style.height = ''
            },
        },
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

    .main-nav {
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease;
        transition: height 0.3s ease;
    }
    .main-nav-enter {
        height: 0;
    }
    .main-nav-leave-to {
        height: 0 !important;
    }

</style>
```